# Periodically updated text is not being displayed

Tags: java, android, for-loop, settext

I have a for loop in which I would like to call the `setText` method. This works without any errors except for the fact that the text does not change until the script is done running. What I want it to do is change the code every time I call the `setText` method. I attached my code below, it should be pretty strait forward.
code:

```
package com.example.zoe.andone;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void startLoop(View view) {
        String string = getString(R.string.hello);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText("starting...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String updated = Integer.toString(i);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText(updated);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText("done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Handler` instead of calling `Thread.sleep(250);` on main Thread

Comment: I am not sure I follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what is called "dropping frames".

**It's time to learn!**

Before going to the answer, let's explain what's going on here.

You probably already know that android has a frame-rate of 60fps (60 frames per sec), which means that every 1/60 sec the screen is rendered and displayed to the user (in order to provide the best definition). It does that by running some rendering code on your app (and everywhere else where there's something to be rendered) every 1/60 sec to compute how the displayed screen should look like at this particular ms (it's is called a frame).

However, the code doing that is running on the UI thread, and if you're doing anything when the rendering tick kicks in, the android framework simply drops that frame (it won't compute it). 
In your case `Thread.sleep(250);` is what causes your frames to be dropped cause it's holding the UI thread for 250 ms in every iteration of your for loop (so it's 250 ms * (10 - 1), that's many frames).

Dropping a frame means seeing no update on the UI.

**Solution**

Instead of using `Thread.sleep(250);` and dropping frames, you should schedule your update tasks to run every 250 ms. That's it.

```
private int i = 0; // Does the trick!
public void startLoop(View view) {
    String string = getString(R.string.hello);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText("starting...");
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i < 10) {
                    String updated = Integer.toString(i);
                    i++;
                    updateHelloOnUiThread(updated);
                } else {
                    updateHelloOnUiThread("done!");
                    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                    i = 0; // For future usages
                }
            }
        },250);
}

private void updateHelloOnUiThread(final String text) {
     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText(text);
            }
     });
}
```

**Further reading**

[Android UI : Fixing skipped frames](https://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/)

[High Performance Android Apps, Chapter 4. Screen and UI Performance](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-android/9781491913994/ch04.html)

Comment: I am using your code, however it is giving me an error saying `Variable 'handler' initializer 'new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { ...' is redundant` I don't know how to fix this :(

Comment: That is what happens when I hover on it. The error that shows up when I try to build it is `Error:(28, 21) error: cannot assign a value to final variable i` thanks!

Comment: cool, thanks again for you help. its complaining that I did not pass `i` into the function any ideas on that?

Comment: Supper! It works(ish) it compiles fine, but it does not output a different number every time, it just stays at zero :(

Comment: Another update (moved i to be a private attribute of your activity)

Comment: Ok working perfectly! Thank you so much for spending the time to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int globalTimer = 0;

                int limitTimer = 10;
                int i = 0;

                // create Timer
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        globalTimer++;
                        //run your code
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello)).setText(i+"");
                        i++;
                        //check if globalTimer is equal to limitTimer
                        if (globalTimer == limitTimer) {
                            timer.cancel(); // cancel the Timer
                        }
                    }

                }, 0, 250);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're calling Thread.sleep on the UI thread.
If the thread is sleeping, it can't update the UI(what's displayed on the screen).